# Installing and configuring MySQL server in a CentOS from the terminal

Tags: mysql, centos

i recently registered for a rackspace cloud hosting account. Everything is running fine already, but i still have to set up the database system.

**I've already done this**

1. yum install php-mysql mysql mysql-server
2. /sbin/chkconfig --levels 235 mysqld on
3. /etc/init.d/mysqld start

Im having trouble with the next steps:

- how can i create databases?
- is there a phpmyadmin package that i can install via console?

Also, am I using the correct levels for the chkconfig?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to run `mysql_secure_installation.`
You can type `mysql -u root`
Then type your usual mysql commands making sure to end with a semicolon.

```
create database employees;
```

As for phpmyadmin I am guessing you can just download it copy it to your webroot and run tar -xvf on it and then access it from your browser after restarting your web daemon since it is purely PHP driven. A package would be a little overkill for such a process.

Comment: Kudos on recommending mysql_secure_installation.  I do not see that often enough in documentation.

Comment: thanks! the mysql_secure_installation tip was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftimt881.wordpress.com%2F2009%2F02%2F17%2Finstalling-phpmyadmin-and-php-52-on-a-centos-52-server%2F&rct=j&q=phpmyadmin%20centos&ei=-yDkTJKTOsKYhQfkqNyrDg&usg=AFQjCNHO61kcgF4HoYMoQq6rPFIZ6AXUAw&cad=rja) on installing phpmyadmin for CentOS.

Here is [another link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-database.html) on creating new databases from Mysql reference manual.